Where does atrun log on a mac?
I have finally gotten atrun working under launchd, but things are disappearing from the queue and things are not happening.
I have done "at -c 34 > ~/do.sh" and executed the resulting script and it worked.
So why atrun is doing something but nothing is happening, must be in the logs, but I cannot find the atrun logs.
Likely something about permissions for file access.

Turns out it logs to /var/mail/
My issue was giving full disk access to atrun
